# Split string and get delimiter as return as well

Tags: php, split, explode

I would like to split a string by an array of delimiters, and also get feedback what the delimiter was.

Example:
`$mystring = 'test+string|and|hello+word';`
`$result = preg_split('/\+,|/+', $mystring);`

I would like an array as return with *something like this*:
`$return[0] = array('test','+');`
`$return[1] = array('string','|');`

thnx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE option for [preg_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

**EDIT**

Example:

```
$mystring = 'test+string|and|hello+word';
$result = preg_split('/([\+|,])/', $mystring, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: thnx Mark (for answer and fast reply)!

Answer (score 0):

I did not know about `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` before writing my answer. It's definitely the clearer than using `preg_match_all`:

```
<?php
$s = 'a|b|c,d+e|f,g';
if (preg_match_all('/([^+,|]+)([+,|])*/', $s, $matches)) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
    echo("got '{$matches[1][$i]}' via delimiter '{$matches[2][$i]}'\n");
  }
}
```